# use select case result in other select

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need to calculate in case statements some values from different fields in SQL Oracle

```
select 
         field01
        ,field02
        ,case field03
             when 'calc1' then field01 - field02
             when 'calc2' then field01 + field02
        end as AmountCalc
       ,case AmountCalc
             when 0 then 'amount is 0'
             else 'Greater than 0'
        end as result
from myTable
```

the query does not recognize field 'AmountCalc' in second case statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Correct.  That is how SQL is supposed to work and how Oracle does work.  Column aliases cannot be re-used in the same  query where they are defined.

Comment: Case expressions, not statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the case statement in select with this,

```
case (case field03
                 when 'calc1' then field01 - field02
                 when 'calc2' then field01 + field02
            end) when 0 then 'amount is 0'
                 else 'Greater than 0'
            end as result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with nested queries:

```
select field01
     , field02
     , AmountCalc
     , case AmountCalc
            when 0 then 'amount is 0'
            else 'Greater than 0'
       end as result
from 
( select field01
       , field02
       , case field03
              when 'calc1' then field01 - field02
              when 'calc2' then field01 + field02
         end as AmountCalc
  from myTable
)
```

Comment: I this this can work for me, but not easy due to several nested queries and joins. I posted a simplified version.
Thanks¡